# How to move everything following a dash to a new column?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that has a single column of text with a dash (-) separating different lines. I would like to move everything below a dash to a new column. My input file looks like this:

```
jim
bob
-
sally 
sue 
ed
-
bill 
-
jerry
curly
phil
-
```

I would like my output file to look like this:

```
jim    sally    bill    jerry
bob    sue      -       curly
-      ed               phil
       -                -
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have a real data set that is much larger, you should mention that in you Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this for a input-file called `input`:

```
 csplit -f tempfile input '/-/+1' '{*}'; paste tempfile*
```

With `csplit` we generate one file for each "column" in the desired output (`tempfile01`, `tempfile02`, ...).
Next, we merge these temporary files. With the given sample input, the output of the above command is:

```
jim sally   bill    jerry   
bob sue     -       curly   
-   ed              phil    
    -               -
```

It might be a good idea to add `rm tempfile*` to do the necessary cleanup.

```
csplit -f tempfile input '/-/+1' '{*}'; paste tempfile* > output; rm tempfile*
```

Comment: @F. Knorr.  something new for me. I thought I knew everything already :)

Answer (score 1):

I did not try this myself, so it's unlikely that it will work the way you wish.  Here's an opportunity to think about it and make it work the way you want.  Feel free to edit this post after you get it "right".

```
BEGIN {
    column = 1;
}

/^-$/ {
    column++;
    row = 1;
    next;
}

{
    Word[column,row] = $1;
    Rows[column] = ++row;
}

END {
    for (col = 1; col < column; col++) {
        for (row = 1; row < Rows[col]; row++) {
            printf ("%s\t", Word[col,row]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting exercise, my `gawk` proposition:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{row=col=0}
      {d[col][row]=d[col][++row]=$1}
      $1=="-"{col++
              if (row>mrow){
                mrow=row
                }
              row=0
              next}
       END{
         for (r=0;r<=mrow;r++) {
           for (c=0;c<=col;c++) {

            printf("%s\t",d[c][r])
            }
            print ""
        }}' file
```

**Results**

```
jim    sally    bill    jerry       
bob    sue      -       curly       
-      ed               phil        
       -                -
```